# Merging Columns from Differerent Sheets into single sheet in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Actually, I am having Four CSV files which consists of one column in each file.Now I have to merge these four columns from four different files(columns of varying Size) into One single sheet.

I tried many things,but they are merging in a single column itself.... But I want to merge those four different columns separately in one sheet.

File1:Sheet1

- ***Column1***
- data1
- data2
- data3

File 2:Sheet1

***Column1***

- data1
- data2

File 3:Sheet1

***Column1***

- data1
- data2
- data3

File 4 :Sheet1 :

***Column1***

- data1
- data2

Now I want to merge these four columns from these 4 sheets into a single sheet having four columns like this

New File--->Sheet1(only sheet)

- ***column1   |    column1(of sheet1 of file2)  |     column1(of sheet1 of file3)   |      column1(of sheet1 of file4)***

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('filename1.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel('filename2.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
df3 = pd.read_excel('filename3.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
df4 = pd.read_excel('filename4.xlsx',sheet_name=None)

final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only one column in each sheet,

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx',sheet_name=None)

final_df = pd.concat(list(df.values()),ignore_index=True,axis=1)

final_df.columns =df.keys()

print(final_df)
```

Comment: But I am having four different files...and only  one column in each file (each file consists of only one sheet)....Now Which file name i should give in the line "df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx',sheet_name=None)"

Comment: It works, but I have removed the list function---Tks